# How to find an actor in caf

Tags: c++, c++-actor-framework

I started to play around with caf and using it to represent a graph.
Since this graph is unidirected I can create the actors that I need and link them accordingly, but now I want to find a specific actor identified by it's name.

```
class node_actor : public event_based_actor{
    std::string m_name;
    ...
};

int main(){
    auto entry_actor = spawn<node_actor>();
    // node_actor will spawn other actors with names
    // like this: node_actor will spawn node1
    // node1 will spwan node2
    // node2 will spwan node3 and so on

    // now I want to send a message to node2
    scoped_actor self;
    self->send(n2, 42});
    ...
}
```

What would be the best way to find `n2`?
Can this be handled by a group, broadcasting a message? E.g like this:

```
{
    auto g = group::get("local", "Node events");
    auto entry_actor = spawn_in_group<node_actor>(g);
    // change all nodes to call spawn_in_group

    scoped_actor self;
    self->send(g, name, 42})
}
```

If so wouldn't that be much overhead, because all nodes must be checked if they match the message?
Or are there other ways that I did not find in the docs yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the group is a good idea because it also works distributed. You can have a better scalability by announcing each spawned actor to the group instead of broadcasting the messages.

Each actor that needs a `name <-> actor` mapping would then subscribe to the group (before you actually spawn your nodes). Whenever you spawn a new node, you send its name along with its handle to the group and each listener adds this mapping to its local state (or ignores the message if it is only interested in a few selected names).

In case you have a lot of actors that need the name mapping and you don't want to replicate the mapping many times, you could also use a single actor instead of a group that stores a map and can be queried by others whenever they need to resolve a name.

Your third option is to use the actor registry, but this will only work locally and only if you can use `atom` names. If this matches your use case, then you can register new actors via `detail::singletons::get_actor_registry()->put_named(key, value);` and retrieve them via `detail::singletons::get_actor_registry()->get_named(key);`. I usually don't recommend features from the `detail` namespace, but this particular feature will make its way to the public API in 0.15. By the way, you can create an `atom_value` dynamically, but you are of course limited to 10 characters and are only allowed to use alphanumeric characters.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try. One more thing since I did not find it in the docs. Can I use the second group parameter to partition my groups. E.g `group::get("local", "EvenNodes")` and `group::get("local", "OddNodes")` to make two node spaces?

Comment: Yes, the second parameter is any user-defined identifier (string). You can create as many groups as you want.

Comment: What about `ConfigServ` and state-based actors with a `name` member?

Comment: @mavam `ConfigServ` is just a node-local key-value store. In this case, there's no benefit in using it over the registry. The `name` of an actor is never evaluated by CAF for anything but logging.

Comment: Wouldnt it be possible to use one group for each actor? This way you would not need to use the detail namespace and dont need a local array/map to access. This would even work distributed.... Or am i wrong?

Comment: I don't see what you get by using one group per actor. Name-based access? In any case is a 1:1 mapping between groups and actors quite expensive.